# Is using more JPanels and the use of the setBounds() method okay?

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, setbounds

I have written many simple GUIs, they worked fine. However as a beginner I always think that my way of writing user interfaces is not very good practice.

Is it proper practice if one uses more panels to get the desired interface? Also is the use of the `setBounds()` method good?

Answer (score 0):

1. The less sub-components you use, the more responsive your UI is going to be. Simply because it has less things to deal with.
2. I would not recommend using 'setBounds` as it is creates inflexible UI in most cases. I would encourage you to start using layouts such as [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) etc. The most versatile of them is [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Here is more general information about Swing layouts: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html